# Hand setting a hard driven ball (beach volleyball)

Tags: rules, beach-volleyball

In [FIVB Offical Beach Volleyball Rules 2017-2020](https://www.fivb.org/EN/Refereeing-Rules/Documents/FIVB-BeachVolleyball_Rules_2017-2020-EN-v05.pdf), which rule allows for a double contact while using an overhand finger action on a hard driven ball?

I see an exception for Extended contacts:

> 9.2.2.4 Extended contacts: In defensive action of a hard driven ball, the ball contact can be extended momentarily even if an overhand
>   finger action is used.

---

The only information I found supporting the double contact was from the [2015 Beach Volleyball Rules Casebook](http://www.fivb.org/EN/Refereeing-Rules/documents/2015-Beach-Volleyball-Rules-Casebook.pdf), case 5.3.11 (5.20)

**Question**

> 5.3.11 (5.20) Is it allowed to play a ball as a hard driven ball (i.e. by momentary extended contact with hands) if the ball is coming from
>   the opponent’s block? Ruling

**Answer** (emphasis mine)

> Yes. This is legal if satisfying the requirements of a hard driven
>   ball defence. The ball rebounding or being deflected off the block is
>   considered as an attack hit and in this case the ball may be caught
>   momentarily with hands. **It may also be double contacted with fingers**.
>   Rule 9.2.2.1

Comment: I don't understand the bounty you've added here - which official sources would you like to see *other* than the official rulebook and casebook?

Comment: @PhilipKendall - I was looking for an additional source confirming that the rule has changed. It doesn't have to be an "official source", but something that supports the rule change.

Comment: @Aducci check this PDF file from this [link](https://volleyballengland.org/~media/docs/FIVB%20Official%20Beach%20Volleyball%20Rules%202017-2020%20Changes%20to%20Previous%20Edition.pdf)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a change in the rules from the [2015-2016 rules](http://www.fivb.org/EN/Refereeing-Rules/Documents/FIVB_BeachVolleyball_Rules_2015-2016_EN_V3_20150205.pdf) to the 2017-2020 rules. The [2017 casebook](http://www.fivb.org/EN/Refereeing-Rules/Documents/2017_Beach_Volleyball_Rules_Casebook_v21.04.2017.pdf) does *not* contain the "It may also be double contacted with the fingers" statement.

In the 2015-2016 rules, rule 9.2.3.2 is the bit which allowed double contact on a hard-driven ball:

> [A double contact is not a fault] at the first hit of the team, unless it is played overhand using fingers
>   (exception Rule 9.2.2.1), the ball may contact various parts of the body
>   consecutively, provided that the contacts occur during one action.

This is a bit confusing as it is an exception to an exception to an exception. The logic is:

- A double contact is a fault
- Unless it is at the first hit of a team
- But it is a fault if the ball is played overhead with the fingers
- Unless it was a hard driven ball, in which case it's not a fault again.

In the 2017-2020 rules, 9.2.2.2 makes it clear that this situation *is* a fault:

> During the first hit of the team if it is played
>   overhand using fingers, the ball may NOT contact the fingers/ hands
>   consecutively, even if the contacts occur during one action.

Comment: Thank you for walking me through the exception logic. It seems weird to allow for extended contact, but not allow double contact. I can't imagine a situation where you successfully contact the ball cleanly with your hands on a hard driven ball (no double contact), but you need to have an extended contact with the ball.

Comment: I don't see rule 9.2.2.2  in the 2017-2020 rules. Was that removed?

Comment: So was this a fault, since its the first hit?
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iEztujOJ2iA

Answer (score 3):

As of 2017. First contact rules are:
Double contact ok if one motion using anything other than a volley(o/h using fingers), 9.2.2.2
If you DO volley, then a double is never allowed. A momentary catch is allowed but only on a hard driven ball. 9.2.2.4. HDB is determined by speed of attack, reactionary time of def player and depth of play. Did the def player have time to adapt to play ball?  Strength speed and depth all are considered.   Players often confuse these 2 rules. For better understanding of the rules, the referee guidelines and casebook offer excellent clarification.